# Strange behaviour when declaring a global variables - Error (logs): "ss.getSheetByName is not a function"

Tags: google-apps-script

Hope somebody can help me.

The script will not even allow me to declare global variables. This code was working flawlessly and it stopped working for most users, still works with some users in our company's Google Workspace. Really strange:

Below is how the code starts (declaring global variables).

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var cotizadorss =  ss.getSheetByName("Cotizador");
var financiass = ss.getSheetByName("Financiamiento");
var pedidoss = ss.getSheetByName("Pedido");
var compartirss = ss.getSheetByName("VtaCompartida");
```

Error (log):

```
TypeError: ss.getSheetByName is not a function
at [unknown function](Logica:2:23)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be related to this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190637756

In my case, I had a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) (onOpen) that would throw a similar error and prevent the script from running. Changing it to an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) calling the same function solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, issue solved without intervention, surely a bug on Google's end.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Issue seems to have been solved by Google (bug).

Answer (score 0):

I read earlier on the Reddit apps script forum about [this same issue happening](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAppsScript/comments/nw2iky/google_sheets_stopped_working_typeerror/) to them.  Users there reported that unchecking "Enable Chrome V8 runtime" fixed their problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, issue solved without intervention, surely a bug on Google's end.